# How can I add a title to a list of plots based on values of the listed df's?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here's that illustrates the obstacle I'm facing.

```
library(tidyverse)

co2_list <- CO2 %>%
  group_split(Type)


reprex_fun <- function(x){
  x %>%
    ggplot(aes(conc, uptake)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~Plant, ncol = 2)
}

lapply(co2_list, reprex_fun)
```

[image: plot 1]
[image: plot 2]

Since the listed dataframes are based on the Type value,
How can I add the corresponding title with the type, to the plots I just made?

Comment: Does adding `+ ggtitle(x$Type[[1]])` to the plotting function not help?

Comment: That doesn't do it when put inside the function

Comment: It works for me when I put it at the end of the function calls to ggplot's functions. Does it not even work for the reprex? Does it return an error?

Comment: My bad, I was trying to add it with a pipe operator, your solution works for my dataset too, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try `labs`, similar to `ggtitle`:

```
#Data
data("CO2")
#Plot
co2_list <- CO2 %>%
  group_split(Type)

#Function

reprex_fun <- function(x){
  x %>%
    ggplot(aes(conc, uptake)) +
    geom_point() +
    labs(title = unique(x$Type))+
    facet_wrap(~Plant, ncol = 2)
}

#Plots

lapply(co2_list, reprex_fun)
```

[image]